# Где и как можно хранить информацию пользователей которые записались через telegram бота

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot

Пишу бота для салона красоты в учебных целях. Пытаюсь реализовать запись к парикмахеру,но не знаю где и как проверять эти данные.

Пользователь нажимает на кнопку записаться, ему предлагается выбрать день далее время.

Но как хранить эти данные и проверят что бы пользователи не записывались на одно и тоже время.

Как мне сделать проверку времени и даты которое уже занято и что бы бот показывал только свободные временные отметки и даты.

Я думаю что для этого надо как то хранить эти записи но где и как правильно и лучше будет не знаю.
Подскажите в какую сторону смотреть .

Comment: Если коротко - то в базе данных.

Comment: а по подробней можно типа создать базу с таблицей дни недели и туда записывать ?

Comment: Как вариант - в таблице записей пару дату и время сделать уникальными (unique constraint), тогда физически нельзя будет записаться на ту же дату и время, при попытке такой записи будет вылетать ошибка, нужно будет ее обрабатывать и писать клиенту, что дата уже занята.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Прикрути SQL.
Вот пример моего кода на JS.
Пользователь добавляется в БД при нажатии кнопки /start.
Тебе понадобиться две таблицы. Для юзеров с внешним ключом и вторая для даты записи.
Можно и в одну затолкать но это не совсем правильно.

```
const user = require('../login')
const { Client } = require('pg')

const client = new Client({
    port:     user.db.port,
    user:     user.db.user,
    host:     user.db.host,
    database: user.db.database,
    password: user.db.password
})

client.connect()


async function insertPerson(from){

    const values = [from.id,from.first_name,from.username]
    const query_insert = `INSERT INTO person (id,first_name,username)
                          VALUES ($1,$2,$3)`

    client
          .query(query_insert,values)
          .then(res=> {
           console.log(res.rows[0])
          })
          .catch(e => console.error(e.stack))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Код может быть любой. Главное - это хранить всю информацию в базе данных. Бот - будет обращаться к информации в ней, чтобы выбрать именно свободное для записи время. Например, Firebird - бесплатная СУБД.

Comment: "Мыши, станьте ёжиками"... :) По сути данный ответ мало чем отличается от комментария insolor двухлетней давности.